# Bounty (half bounty) awarding is not working?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

colmcq was kind enough to offer a bounty on this question:
[methods for evaluating a complex information architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/8267/95)

In a comment, he said that he intended to award the full bounty to [my answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8267/methods-for-evaluating-a-complex-information-architecture/8358#8358).

I guess that the absence of full bounty awarding is a matter of EBCAC error, but it might be worth some investigation.

Nevertheless, half the bounty was supposed to be awarded to the highest voted answer that was created after the bounty started, and that had at least 2 upvotes.  I can't see that this happened...

---

P.S: No offense on the EBCAC-designation!
P.P.S: I'm not trying to be rep-greedy, jusst trying to report a bug :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We extended the bounty auto-award for 24 hours based on <s>an epic amount of user whining</s> valued community feedback.

[A grace period of one day to award the bounty after expiration (without remaining featured, of course)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037)

So just wait.

Comment: OK.  I would expect to find that information in the last bullet point here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

Comment: I just received the full bounty. Was that supposed to happen?   I cant see that colmcq received any benefactor-badge.

Comment: another special case rule we implemented; if the owner accepts an answer during the bounty period, we assume they wanted the acceptee to have the bounty.